# postgresql 9.2 send data to firebird

Tags: postgresql, firebird, postgresql-9.2, firebird2.5

I am trying to send data from postgresql 9.2 database to firebird database. I can not find ways to do it successfully. I've tried postgresql 9.2 dblink but I can't still send data to firebird.

Comment: DBLink is **only** to connect two Postgres servers. If at all, using a foreign data wrapper would work. There is one [Firebird FDW](https://github.com/ibarwick/firebird_fdw/) but it's marked as "work in progress" (and seems to be abandoned)  If you are on Linux, you could try one of the generic ODBC (or JDBC) wrappers. But I don't think they are in a good shape either: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fdw

Comment: Thank you. May I know if you had known foreign servers on Postgresql that enables the synchronization of the database of Postgresql  and FireBird?

Comment: It's in the link in my comment.